# Page not found when visiting an Ubercart google_checkout URL

Tags: ubercart

When I visit `mysite.com/google_checkout?serial-number=123-456-7`, I get

> The requested page "/google_checkout?serial-number=123-456-7" could not be found.

Otherwise, then I have a working [Google Checkout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Checkout) button on my site and everything seems to be configured. How can I get the callback URL to work?

Comment: What makes you think it _would_ work? Do you have a module installed that provides that path? Or custom code that does it? Or a menu entry? Help us out a bit :)

Comment: That's the URL that the module "Google Checkout" is telling me to use at: mysite.com/#overlay-context=user&overlay=admin/store/settings/payment/method/google_checkout